# Localize x:String

Tags: xaml, localization, windows-8

I saw such questions on MSDN, but they were not answered. So I can localize all my controls using x:Uid and specific key format in *.resw file. But how do I localize x:String? For example this:

```
<x:String x:Key="AppName">My App</x:String>
```

I know some workarounds. But are there any nice approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is impossible now. Should use `x:String` only for strings that are not supposed to be localized (e.g. App Name). Otherwise, using `TextBlock` or some other text controls is preferred

Answer (score 1):

There is an msdn post on doing that [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/04/26/localize-windows-8-application.aspx).  The essence of it is something like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="MyTextBlock" FontSize="24.667" Text="Design Placeholder" />
```

> Notice the `x:Uid` value here.  This now maps back to the key in your
>   RESW file.  Anything with that starting key will have properties
>   merged into it.  So we can have a key in our RESW for “Text” using the
>   key name MyTextBlock.Text with a value of “Hello World” and the
>   runtime will do the replacement for you.

Steps:

1. Create a textblock with the `x:Uid` property defined.
2. Create a RESW file for your language appropriately named for your localization
3. Add strings to your RESW to replace the property in your textblock

Comment: As I mentioned, I can localize TextBlock.Text, Button.Content and other controls where I can use {Control}.{Property} syntax. But I have problems doing the same thing for `x:String`

Comment: Ah, sorry.  You probably can't use this method for that.  Strings don't have dependency properties which are required for binding.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your x:string?  Maybe there is a different way you could do it.

Comment: I want to localize them without writing any code the same way that I do for controls. I also don't want to change my `x:String` resources to something else

Comment: But why x:string?  Are you using it as an app level resource or something?

Comment: Yes, I use x:String as some app level resources. Actually the app name was defined as x:String in BasicPage (and all others in Visual Studio) template, so I decided to follow that practice and use x:String everywhere I can. I'm not quite sure if it is correct, but that's not so important here. I just want to know if there are some known approaches for such cases.

Comment: I think the best strategy would be to get rid of your x:Strings.  You can't bind to their properties and they're not as flexible and simply putting the value in a resource file is.

Comment: String objects were simply never intended to be used the way you're using them.

Comment: I guess replacing x:String is the only way then. However, it is rather weird that some binding is needed for assigning constants. Why not just set the value once at app start? Anyway, thanks for clarification, I'm not sure what i should mark as answer though

Comment: By binding I meant dependency property.  That's just a guess, but it is true that certain data types are not first class citizens in xaml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771178.aspx